# Подключение роутера к сети организации в режиме AP

Tags: сеть, wifi, роутер, d-link

Имеется роутер D-Link DAP-1360 ревизия D1, который необходимо подключить в режиме точки доступа (AP) к одному из коммутаторов в сети. DHCP сервер расположен на коммутаторе Dell PowerConnect 7048. Dell воткнут в маршрутизатор Cisco.
Установки для оборудования:
Default Gateway (для D-Link и для Dell): 10.15.1.1
IP коммутатора Dell: 10.15.1.250
IP роутера: 10.15.1.160(статический)
Режим работы D-Link выставляю как "AP"
DHCP сервер на D-Link выключен
WiFi режим включен, настройки безопасности установлены (WPA2-PSK)
Телефон видит эту точку доступа, но при подключении выдает, что нет доступа к интернету и получает IP адрес из APIPA, а не с DHCP сервера (Dell)

Comment: Т.е,  я правильно понял,  вы не предприняли никаких действий,  и хотите чтобы кто-то  сделал за вас вашу работу?

Comment: @694201970 , Поняли не правильно. Есть сеть организации, всё настроено и работает давно. Подключаю D-link к любому из коммутаторов сети, выставляю на нем статический IP (10.15.1.160), маску подсети 255.255.255.0, настраиваю WiFi и т.д., по логике, должно работать. Пинговал DHCP сервер с роутера, пинг идет, обратно тоже, компьютеры пингуют роутер. Также, пробовал выставить режим Роутера на D-Link, ничего не меняется. Подключал как в разъем LAN, так и в разъём Internet. В любом случае, нет доступа к интернету. Может из-за прокси? хотя не должно.

Comment: выставил стандартный IP адрес, указанный на обороте устройства (192.168.0.50). всё заработало, но почему-то выдал ip адрес из dhcp пула. так и должно быть? не будет ли конфликтов?

Comment: нет,  конфликтов не будет!

Comment: будем пробовать, дело было в том, что все ip из пула были заняты, когда освобождался ip моего ПК, его занимал телефон. планируем расширить диапазон пула. всем спасибо!

Comment: на этом, всё-таки, проблемы не кончились. wifi появился, работает, но, в организации есть vypress chat, так вот, при подключении роутера в сеть, этот чат не показывает пользователей, как быть? уже перенастраивали порт на коммутаторе, в который подключен роутер, не помогло. приходится выбирать - или wifi или чат