# Падает VyPress Chat при подключении роутера к существующей сети

Tags: ip, wifi, switch, chat

Всем привет, у меня уже был вопрос с подключением к существующей сети организации роутера D-Link DAP-1360 ревизия D1 ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162711/Подключение-роутера-к-сети-организации-в-режиме-ap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162711/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5-ap))
Wi-Fi был настроен и работает. Доступ к интернету есть.
На компьютеры домена установлен VyPress Chat в сетевых настройках которого выбрана Групповая адресация (IP Multicast) и указана мультикаст группа. Чат работает нормально, до подключения к сети роутера. После подключения его в сеть, пользователи в чате пропадают и остаешься один. Иногда показывает 10 или 30 пользователей, но не всех. Соответственно, после отключения роутера от сети, чат показывает всех пользователей.
К слову, на коммутаторах созданы по 2 vlan (для компов это 10.15.1.0, для ip-телефонов и принтеров это 10.10.15.0), порты настроены в режиме general. Ставил порт (к которому подключен роутер) в режим trunk, в режим access, ничего не меняется кроме того, что wifi перестает работать(нет доступа к интернету).

Answer (score 0):

Решено.
В настройках чата выставил Широковещательные рассылки, выгрузил xml файл с сетевыми настройками чата, добавил в него ip-адреса всех пользователей сети, положил файл в общую папку на сервере и выбрал в настройках чата "Брать сетевые настройки из файла", указав путь к файлу xml.
Закинул в политику домена batch файл со следующими строками для запуска его при входе пользователя с систему и установки сетевых настроек чата:

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\VyPRESS\Chat\Settings /v NetSettingsFileName /t REG_SZ /d "ПУТЬ К XML ФАЙЛУ С НАСТРОЙКАМИ" /f              
REG ADD HKCU\Software\VyPRESS\Chat\Settings /v LoadNetSettingsFromFile /t REG_DWORD /d "0x00000001" /f


REG ADD HKU\S-1-5-21-3170204770-3100349960-*********-****\Software\VyPRESS\Chat\Settings /v NetSettingsFileName /t REG_SZ /d "ПУТЬ К XML ФАЙЛУ С НАСТРОЙКАМИ" /f              
REG ADD HKU\S-1-5-21-3170204770-3100349960-*********-****\Software\VyPRESS\Chat\Settings /v LoadNetSettingsFromFile /t REG_DWORD /d "0x00000001" /f
```